# How to set the default image resolution for exporting?

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

I know `Export["image.png", image, ImageResolution -> 300]`.

But it there a way to set the default value for `ImageResolution`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Export` does not seem to work with `SetOptions` so I'm afraid its not possible.

You can make your own like this:

```
 export[args__] := Export[args, ImageResolution -> 300];
```

then do

```
 export["image.png", image];
```